# Is it possible for there to be Kohanim & Levyim that are not Jewish?

Tags: kohen-priest, judaism

Due to the fact that Jewishness is determined by matrilineal descent and priesthood by patrilineal descent.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You have to be Jewish first before you are considered a Cohen or a Levi.